# Swift 4 How to create an in app photo gallery like the built in photos app?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I'm loading images from the camera roll into the app as UIImages. How do I create a gallery to display all these images (Grid view, user can tap on an image thumbnail and scroll left/right to navigate)?

Also, I would like to know how I can handle large amounts of images being loaded into the app. I'm thinking something along the lines of loading image thumbnails as the user scrolls down the gallery, but I'm not sure how that is done either.